# Strict aliasing error for fp16 to fp32 conversion

Tags: c, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I have a function for fp16 to fp32 conversion

```
static float fp16_to_fp32(const short in){
    signed int t1, t2, t3;
    float out = 0;

    t1 = (in & 0x7fff) << 13 + 0x38000000;
    t2 = (in & 0x8000) << 16;
    t3 = in & 0x7c00;
    
    t1 = (t3==0 ? 0 : t1);
    t1 |= t2;

    *((unsigned int*)&out) = t1;
    
    return out;
}
```

***error: dereferencing typed-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
in *((unsigned int*)&out) = t1;***

How can I solve this? (can't change type of argument `in` )

Comment: For C it's allowed to do type-punning through unions. Otherwise you can use `char` pointers or arrays as an intermediate step (for example

Comment: @NateEldredge Why `sizeof(short)`?

Comment: @MikeCAT: Sorry, was looking at `in` instead of `t1`.  Anyway your answer covers everything.

Comment: If this is for modern x86 processors, you may also be interested in `_cvtsh_ss` and related intrinsics

Comment: Major bug: + has higher precedence than <<. I doubt you wanna shift `13 + 0x38000000` bits to the left... a decent compiler will tell you as much.

Comment: Also, can't reproduce the error on gcc. Which compiler, port and options are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`memcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) for copying data.

Also note that `+` operator has higher precedence than `<<` operator, so the line `t1 = (in & 0x7fff) << 13 + 0x38000000;` won't work as expected.

```
#include <string.h> /* for memcpy() */

static float fp16_to_fp32(const short in){
    signed int t1, t2, t3;
    float out = 0;

    t1 = ((in & 0x7fff) << 13) + 0x38000000; /* add parenthesis */
    t2 = (in & 0x8000) << 16;
    t3 = in & 0x7c00;
    
    t1 = (t3==0 ? 0 : t1);
    t1 |= t2;

    memcpy(&out, &t1, sizeof(out)); /* use memcpy() for copying */
    
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) I forgot parenthesis while writing code here on platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type punning through `union` to dodge strict aliasing:

```
union type_punner
{
  unsigned int i;
  float f;
} out = {.i = t1};
return out.f;
```

This assuming int and float are the same size, so it isn't very portable code.

You could also compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `out` as a float pointer then return `*out`

Comment: That would violate strict aliasing too, assuming you intend to do something like `out = (float *)&t1`.